# Can I use one exchange server for two companies?

Tags: exchange, configuration

I hope this is the right place for my question.

We are supporting a company that is about to merge with another one. Both of them are fairly small. They want to keep using their mails and the domains as usual. i.e. user@companyABC.com and user@companyXYZ.com.

I am not sure witch version of exchange they have already installed at their server, so I am going for the worst case scenario, that is for exchange 2003.

Can we use only one Exchange server to support both companies mails?

Depending on the answer to this, the other thing they have asked us is if some of the users, i.e. secretaries can have access to both companies contacts and calendars. 
Can this be done?

If you could point some sites with configuration information... I would appreciate it!!!

Thanks

Comment: Only thing I know is that its a megaton of work and hassle of getting separate global address lists working. Be aware!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following links from Microsoft Social Technet may help you:

- [2 companies. Should we have 1 exchange or 2?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/3f145a48-35bb-4de1-9e28-3a79fbc15ad4)
- [How to host two companies with one Exchange server 2003](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/71d7e72c-d139-4031-887a-ad84d68ccca7)

Comment: Very usefull links! I will have to do my reading now!

Answer (score 1):

Your Exchange server is able to happily support any number of email domains, so in regards to that, yes you can.

That said, the question is more whether your Active Directory and Infrastructure can support it? Are they going to be keeping their domain and setting up a trust between domains, or are you moving everyone from their domain, to new accounts on your domain, or something different.

You can only have 1 Exchange organisation in a Forest, so you will need to have some decision about what to do with Exchange.

Comment: I am not really sure how they have their Active Directory setup... I will also need more information on that!